# Using OEEL library in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to translate a Google Earth Engine project from JavaScript to the Python API. My project involves the Savitzky-Golay filter. I used this method from the [OEEL library](https://www.open-geocomputing.org/OpenEarthEngineLibrary/#.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter) using the following:

```
var oeel=require('users/OEEL/lib:loadAll');
var order = 2;
var sgFilteredCol = oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(
  eqSpacedCol, 
  maxDiffFilter,
  distanceFunction,
  order)
```

Complete example [here](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/end-to-end-gee.html#savitzky-golay-smoothing).

If it is possible to use the OEEL library functions from Python API, then how do I use the `SavatskyGolayFilter()` function?

Comment: According to their site it should be possible: https://www.open-geocomputing.org/OpenEarthEngineLibrary/#